# Interspersing Cells From Different Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a rather simple Excel problem that I cannot seem to solve using the fill handle. I have spent two days developing complex formulas to extract and format hexadecimal test data but I'm stuck on what seems a trivial problem. It is best described with an image(I need 10 rep to post directly):

[image]

I have a pair of columns of 128 rows, each row across the columns contains consecutive data entries. I want to arrange the data in a single in-order column, as show above. I tried manually entering a series of functions in column D (`=A1`,`=B1`,`=A2`,`=B2` etc.) for the first several rows and using the fill handle, but it ends up skipping large chunks of the data.

There must be a simple solution for this sort of rearrangement but I cannot work it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `=INDEX($A$1:$B$128,INT((ROW()+1)/2),ABS(MOD(ROW(),2)-2))`. Put in C1 and fill down. If you are putting it somewhere else that doesn't begin at row 1, subtract (start row - 1) from each call to `ROW()`.

Comment: +1 for the formula im always amazed how people understand and come up with those things ;)

Comment: Fantastic, the operation is obviously more complex than I first thought! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In `D1` enter

```
    =INDIRECT("a"&QUOTIENT(ROW()+1,2))
```

then in `D2` enter

```
    =INDIRECT("b"&QUOTIENT(ROW()+1,2))
```

then select `D1:D2` and drag the fill handle in `D2` down to twice as many rows you have in columns `A:B`.

Answer (score 0):

in vba, just increment your variables before ending the for, next loop like so:

```
Sub crundle()
     i = 1
     j = 1
     For i = 1 To 128

         ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i) = "=a" & j
         ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i + 1) = "=b" & j

         i = i + 1
         j = j + 1

     Next i


End Sub
```